# Image Slider implemented using Carousel is not working

Tags: react-native, carousel

I am working on an App which can display a simple Image Slider using Carousel.
I have used the Carousel from "react-native-banner-carousel" library.

Code:

ImageSlider.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-native-banner-carousel';
import { StyleSheet, Image, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const BannerWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const BannerHeight = 260;

const images = [
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61McsadO1OL.jpg",
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51vlGuX7%2BFL.jpg",
    "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/717DWgRftmL._SX522_.jpg"
];

export default class ImageSlider extends React.Component {
    renderPage(image, index) {
        return (
            <View key={index}>
                <Image style={{ width: 500, height: BannerHeight }} source={{ uri: image }} />
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Carousel
                    autoplay
                    autoplayTimeout={5000}
                    loop
                    index={0}
                    pageSize={BannerWidth}
                >
                    {images.map((image, index) => this.renderPage(image, index))}
                </Carousel>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
});
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import  Header from './components/Header';
import ImageSlider from './components/ImageSlider';

class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header headerText = "SAMPLE APP" />
                <ImageSlider  />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I am importing ImageSlider inside the App.js
I am trying the method mentioned in this link: https://github.com/f111fei/react-native-banner-carousel

But the output I am getting is somewhat like this: 
[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: seems like a height problem with the ImageSlider component. Have you tried to set the height of the view inside the ImageSlider component to a fixed value for example 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {
render () {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Header headerText = "SAMPLE APP" />
            <ImageSlider  />
        </View>
    );
 }
}
```

Notice this in the above code

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
```

Hope this will help.!

Comment: can you answer this question as well if possible?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266273/json-value-2-of-type-nsnumber-cannot-be-converted-to-nsstring